# How to make script executable on shell permanently?

Tags: bash, terminal

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3744248/1768191) answer to make a Python script, `gn`, in `/opt/gn` accessible via `Terminal` systemwide in Ubuntu like this:

```
PATH=${PATH}:/opt/gn
```

However, when I restart `Terminal`, I cannot longer execute the script system-wide. I have to retype the command from above.

I tried to copy that `PATH` to the last line of `~/.profile`, but it would not work like that.

How to get permanent execution to a script?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14826325/1549844

Comment: @KevinD: Sorry, actually the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/a/14826325/1768191 is incomplete. The decisive line is missing...

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu you can add additional search paths into `/etc/environment`.
Just append your path at the end of `PATH="..."` adding colon before your path.

After that you must re-login or reboot.

Answer (score 0):

To get it permanent you need to store the updated path to a file that is read by your shell at startup. Try adding the path to your `.bashrc`-file?

See the `INVOCATION`-section in the man-page for bash

The part that applies to your question is

> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started,  bash  reads  and
>          executes  commands  from  /etc/bash.bashrc  and  ~/.bashrc, if these files exist.
>
> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell
>          with  the  --login  option,  it  first  reads and executes commands from the file
>          /etc/profile, if that file  exists.   After  reading  that  file,  it  looks  for
>          ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and exe‐
>          cutes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.

meaning that you simply put your updated path in the wrong file.